# getting properties of a dynamic object returned by newtonsoft.json fails with exception

Tags: c#, json

After successfully deserializing a json file to a dynamic object as in the example:
    dynamic d;

```
using (var jsonFile = System.IO.File.OpenText(>myfile>))
using (JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(jsonFile))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    d = serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader);
}

var propertyCollection = (IDictionary<String, Object>)d;
```

I get the following exception:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in json.exe

Additional information: Impossible to cast objects of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' on 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.

I just copied from one of the examples

Comment: Can you show the Json structure

Comment: You could instruct the deserializer to output a specific type: `serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonTextReader);`. It's not a secret what it's going to be, since you're casting it to a Dictionary right after. You could also use generics to deserialize to a `<T>`.